# Cannot import Python function in Jython

Tags: python, sqlite, jython, importerror

I wrote a Python script which is executed via Jython 2.7. I need SQLite, so I decided to use sqlite3 for Jython ([link](https://pypi.org/project/jython-sqlite3/)) which is under */usr/local/lib/jython/Lib*.

**ghidra_batch.py**

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/jython/Lib")
sys.path.append("/path/to/my/project/directory")
import sqlite3
```

I created another file where I define some functions for my database:

**db.py**

```py
import platform
import sys
if platform.python_implementation == 'Jython':
    sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/jython/Lib")
    sys.path.append("/path/to/my/project/directory")
import sqlite3

def open_db():
   [some code]

def create_schema():
   [some code]
```

Note: I check Python implementation because this script is run also via CPython. I append the path only when run via Jython to make it find its sqlite3 module, in case of CPython standard sqlite3 module is used.

Now my problem happens when I import open_db() in ghidra_batch.py:

```py
from db import open_db
```

The result is the following:

```
ImportError: cannot import name open_db
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens if you add `import db`, `print(db)`, `print(dir(db))` lines in *ghidra\_batch.py* **before** `from db import open_db`?

Comment: try only `import db` and see what happens

Comment: @CristiFati, here the results: ```<java package db 0x2>
['__name__', 'buffers', 'util']
```
@MobrineHayde, ```NameError: global name 'open_db' is not defined```

Comment: So, as you see, it's not the *db* that you think it is (*db.py*).  I don;t know what that module is, but you can work around the problem by renaming your file (*db.py*) to *sqlite\_db\_wrapper.py*, and also modifying your *import* statement.

Comment: You're my savior, saved me the day, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule: when working with *Python*, when something isn't not what you're expecting, simply *print* it.

Your `from db import open_db` line which was triggering that exception "told" me that:

- The *db* module (package) was found
- It's not the one that you're expecting to be (your *db.py*)

That's why I suggested in my comment to *print* information about it (obviously, before the error is hit):

```py
import db
print(db)
print(dir(db))
```

The output confirmed it. So, there is another *db* module which is imported before yours.  I tried replicating your environment (installed *Jython*, but I wasn't able to install *jython-sqlite3*). 
After a bit of research, I think it's [[BitBucket]: Taro L. Saito/sqlite-jdbc/Source - sqlite-jdbc/src/main/java/org/sqlite/DB.java](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) (*sqlite-jdbc* is a *jython-sqlite3* dependency).

The reasonable way is to modify your module name to something else (e.g.: *sqlite_db_wrapper.py*), and also update the *import* statement(s).

As a(n other) general rule, **don't give your modules (common) names that might conflict with modules from *Python*'s library**.